match-data not cleared on failed re-search-forward
I need to make multiples re-search'es in a buffer.
But when the last re-search fails, the match-data  still contains the former result.
foo-bar-baz

(progn
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (re-search-forward "^foo-\\(.*\\)-baz" nil t)
  (message "step 1: %S '%s'" (match-data) (match-string-no-properties 1))
  ;; => step 1: (#<marker at 1 in *scratch*> #<marker at 12 in *scratch*> #<marker at 5 in *scratch*> #<marker at 8 in *scratch*>) ’bar’

  (goto-char (point-min))
  (re-search-forward "^baz-\\(.*\\)-foo" nil t)
  (message "step 2: %S '%s'" (match-data) (match-string-no-properties 1))
  ;; => step 2: (#<marker at 1 in *scratch*> #<marker at 12 in *scratch*> #<marker at 5 in *scratch*> #<marker at 8 in *scratch*>) ’bar’
  ;; expected no match-data
  )

I don't get how to use set-match-data and need to know when the last re-search don't matches.
Any advise on a lispy way to do such re-searches ?
Setting NOERROR to t  seems to the root cause but clearer than excpecting errors everywhere in my re-searches.

As explained in re-search-forward's docstring return nil if no matches found.   So enclosing it in a (if (re-search-forward regex nil t) (message "found") (message "not found")) looks like an acceptable soluce.

Not sure what you're asking, but have you tried using save-match-data?

@Drew, I'll give it a try... But in fact when I made a search and used the result, I dont want to remember the match-data anymore. I was looking for a way to clear the match-data, not to get a New one.

Did you try set-match-data? See (elisp) Entire Match Data.

Match Data tells you "Because the match data normally describe the most recent search only, you must be careful not to do another search inadvertently between the search you wish to refer back to and the use of the match data.  If you can’t avoid another intervening search, you must save and restore the match data around it, to prevent it from being overwritten."

According to @Drew suggestion save-match-data give an all new match-data just as I wanted:
foo-bar-baz

(progn
  (save-match-data
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (re-search-forward "^foo-\\(.*\\)-baz" nil t)
    (message "step 1: %S" (match-string-no-properties 1))) 
;; => step 1 : "bar"

  (save-match-data
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (re-search-forward "^baz-\\(.*\\)-foo" nil t)
    (message "step 2: %S" (match-string-no-properties 1))) 
;; => step 2: no nil
  )


You can accept your own answer.
